# Loading flat files into Android database table

Tags: database, android, sqlite

In Android when you upgrade a database all data is lost.

I'm going through a phase of development right now that is forcing many database upgrades.

I don't want to lose all my data (and have to manually re-enter it) each time I upgrade my database.

I would like to store my data in flat files and load those flat files into their respective tables each time a database upgrade occurs.

What is the way to go about this on the Android platform? Where should I store the data files (`res/raw`)

What sql should I execute to load these files?

Comment: Here is a link to a post about re-importing an existing sqlite db, could be helpful: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 2):

mbaird has a good answer for storing the flat files. But in your case (if I understand you correctly) you can get around it by implementing [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). Just store the database version and pass it to the constructor. Then handle any changes in onUpgrade(). You won't lose all your data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the flat files in `res/raw` unless they are `XML`, in which case I'd put them in `res/xml`.

As for inserting the data in the database, I'd just loop through the values in the flat files and do an insert for each row.

At quick glance I don't see any batch insert methods available in Android.

Just read your flat files in using a `FileReader` or a `XmlPullParser` depending on the file type.

Comment: If your files are in a .csv format can't you just use an import statement or something to import the entire file to a table? ...that is, instead of inserting each row independently.